# Probability of this event of a tuple not being deleted: Is this correct?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

We consider a set of n tuples. Now, among the $2n$ elements, $m$ are deleted uniformly at random.

Now the question is, what is the probability that 1 specific tuple is not deleted.

I thought it would be the following

$$\frac{{{2n-2}\choose m}}{{2n} \choose m}=\frac{(2n-2)!m! (2n-m)!}{m!(2n-2-m)!(2n)!}=\frac{(2n-2)!(2n-m)!}{(2n-2-m)!(2n)!}=\frac{(2n-m)(2n-m-1)}{2n(2n-1)},$$
since there are $2n-2$ good possibilities to choose $m$ from, and $2n$ in total.

Another argument would be the following: Among the $2n$, in the first step $2n-2$ are ok. In the second step $2n-2-1$ out of $2n-1$ are ok. 
Then we get $$\frac{(2n-2)}{2n} \frac{(2n-3)}{2n-1} \frac{(2n-4)}{2n-2} \dotsc \frac{(2n-m-1)}{2n-m+1}=\frac{(2n-m)(2n-m-1)}{2n (2n-1)}.$$
 Is this correct? Can one simplify this? Can one derive this more easily?